# Why does python seem to execute code out of order?

Tags: python

When executed, the `input()` prompt is printed before the `print()` above it.
The result of executing is printing

```
Color1:Guess the code
```

I am using the canopy editor. I have tried `guess[x]=input("Color %s:") % str(x+1)`, and `guess[x]=input("Color"+str(x+1))`

```
guess=[None]*n
print("Guess the code")
for x in range(5):
   tempstring = "Color"+str(x+1)+":"
   guess[x]=input(tempstring)
```

I expect the output to be

```
Guess the code
Color1:
```

then allow the user to input a letter

Comment: Maybe the problem is specific to your editor. Does the problem still occur if you run your script straight from the command line?

Comment: I copied your script (changed the *n to *5 to make it work) and ran it from the command line, and it works as intended.

Your particular editor might be using some weird output buffering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected, when I copy and run this code.

To me it looks like a flushing problem. Can you try forcing flush, with `flush=True` in your print function like following:

```
print("Guess the code", flush=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a 'newline' character or your os equivalent, in the line of code `print("Guess the code")` to

```
print("Guess the code\n")
```

`\n` is new line in reg ex

I believe your os is reading the output into the 'tag' expression `<Guess the Code>` for the input command and the print output. Adding the newline stops the os from thinking it's the tag and changes it to std output.

---

added answer

---

code works on a linux box if you remove the 'asterisk n' in the first line:

```
guess=[None]
print("Guess the code")
for x in range(5):
   tempstring = "Color"+str(x+1)+":"
   guess[x]=input(tempstring)
```

output

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 00:06:43)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Guess the code
Color1:
```

Comment: `print` already adds a newline at the end, so I doubt this could help (nice try, though ;)

Comment: add the newline here:
guess[x]=input(tempstring)
python documentation states built in 'input' command does not write a newline:
input([prompt])
If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.  from web: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input